# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): после обновления Django

Tags: django

Проблема начала проявляться после обновления Django==1.11.5 до Django>=1.11.6 вплоть до последней версии.
На POST запросы получаю 403 Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): //

```
Response Headers:
    Set-Cookie: csrftoken=abcdefjKpanWysuu4kUWxP7mCAYn32WZiPQ7w; expires=Mon, 25 Jan 2021 15:10:51 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
    Set-Cookie: sessionid=some098768514session87id; expires=Mon, 10 Feb 2020 15:10:51 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

```
Request Headers:
    Cookie: sessionid=some098768514session87id; csrftoken=123456789mJgneZvTywedAN8fERpHHDjOLodcS54FptPho
    X-CSRFToken: 123456789mJgneZvTywedAN8fERpHHDjOLodcS54FptPho
```

```
Form Data
csrfmiddlewaretoken: ВащеЧеТоТретьеitU7X6Q9QOMryPw3XANMxaIu0AI67Z4DlbrZQ
```

При этом X-CSRFToken подставляется через $.cookie('csrftoken')

В форме {% csrf_token %}

Запрос отправляется через $.ajax()

Напомню, что до версии 1.11.5 этой проблемы не было

Answer (score 1):

Во всем должен быть порядок. Тем более в списке Middleware

Django в authentication backends дергает auth.login(request, user), где на каждый request генерится свежий csrf_token.

Если 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' разместить выше слоя авторизации, то можно нарваться на спецэффекты, когда страницы открвыаются нормально, но формы не обрабатываются, так как CsrfViewMiddleware реджектит при проверке токена.